# PHP - trying to loop through a checkbox array

Tags: php

I don't get why this code isnt working. I can display the results page with checkboxes:

users.php

```
<form action="view_users.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

//Other code

$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="userlist" name="userlist[]" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>" />
        <?php
        echo nl2br("ID: " . $row["user_id"]. " UserName: ". $row["user_name "]. "\n\n");
    }
} 
?>
```

So its just a page with a list of users with checkboxes next to their ID's and a submit button.
When submitted, I just want to display a list of users that were checked (among other things later).

view_users.php

```
if(isset($_POST['userlist'])){
        foreach ($_POST['userlist'] as $id){
            echo $id;
        }
    }
```

I know there's other questions like this and I looked it up but I still cant get it to work. It just returns a blank page. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know if the `userlist` array has values? Check the browser's `view page source` and ensure that the input `value` attributes have the expected ids. You could also try doing a `var_dump($_POST);` before the if in the `view_users` script to see what's being sent.

Comment: @PaulT. I changed to  ($_POST['userlist'] as $id) to 
foreach ($_POST['userlist'] as $id=>$value) and then ID's I was looking for was in $value. But thanks anyway

Comment: Please see [mcve]. The code you've posted is incomplete and syntactically incorrect. For all we know you've omitted the part that is the root cause of the problem.